# release:prepare mess with SCM url before taging

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I use SVN to version the source files and maven release plugin to create and tag release. My project is a multimodule project.

**Short story**

The release:prepare goal causes both trunk and tags to be tagged in my SCM.

**Long story**

My project is a multi-module project :

```
 bar
    module1
    module2
    ...
    pom.xml
```

The SCM tag is configured like this in my project parent POM bar/pom.xml:

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.mycompany.local/svn/foo/projects/bar/trunk</connection>
  <url>http://svn.mycompany.local/svn/foo/projects/bar/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

When I run :

```
mvn release:prepare -DskipTests=true -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1 -DdryRun=true
```

The SCM tag in pom.xml.tag is modified but not as excepted :

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.mycompany.local/svn/foo/projects/bar/tags/bar-1.0/trunk</connection>
    <url>http://svn.mycompany.local/svn/foo/projects/bar/tags/bar-1.0/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

And if I perform the release:

```
 mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1
```

directory trunk AND tags are tagged in the tags folder. I get this structure in the repository:

```
bar
   /trunk/
        [...]
   /tags
        /bar-1.0
            /trunk
            /tags
```

Then the perform goal fail :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:perform (default-cli) on project bar: Error executing Maven. 
Working directory "C:\projects\foo\bar\target\checkout\bar" does not exist! -> [Help 1]
```

In a manner of fact, I have got this in my target\checkout directory :

```
tags\
trunk\
```

I have got several other projects that work with no problem with the same kind of configuration.

What I checked:
 - My subversion structure follow the conventionnal branches/trunk/tags, so tagBase shouldn't have to be mentionned here
 - The effective POM shows a correct SCM configuration (before tagging of course)
 - Checked of course that SCM url's are correct and point to the location of the pom.xml

So I really do not know where to look at. Is there anyone who had the same problem or have an idea ? What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: First i would suggest to configure the release plugin in the bar-pom with an newer version than 2.0 (cause currently 2.2.2 is the one) and put the information autoVersinSubmodules into the configuration as well(That makes life easier). The given option -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1 does not make sense, cause development version must be suffixed by "-SNAPSHOT" otherwise it's a release and not a developmentVersion. Furthermore add developerConnection as well and add a "/" to the end of "trunk" like this *../trunk/*

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks a lot for you suggestion, that was indeed a plugin version issue. I did not configure it anywhere, assuming that maven automatically used the last version for its own plugins. That was obviously not the case. If you put your comment in an answer, I could mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i would suggest to configure the release plugin in the bar-pom with an newer version than 2.0 (cause currently 2.2.2 is the one) and put the information autoVersinSubmodules into the configuration as well(That makes life easier). The given option -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1 does not make sense, cause development version must be suffixed by "-SNAPSHOT" otherwise it's a release and not a developmentVersion. Furthermore add developerConnection as well and add a "/" to the end of "trunk" like this ../trunk/ 
The maven-release-plugin is related to the Maven Version you are using. The super-pom of Maven defines a set of plugins and their appropriate version as well.